# Understanding TimeZone in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a requirement to store the timestamp column in PST and the same column is being used to partition the table. I see that though I have converted the column value as PST, BigQuery is still showing UTC timezone.

[image]

Is there any way we can store data in a timezone other than UTC? Here is the method which I have used to create this column.

```
public static Timestamp getTimestampInPST() {
    ZonedDateTime nowPST = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST").toZoneId());
    return Timestamp.valueOf(nowPST.toLocalDateTime());
}
```

Comment: Could you share the full error message you get? Also, is the table created already? Can you also share the schema?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you can use 'Datetime' data type.
Output difference is given below for the query:-

Query:

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as TS, CURRENT_DATETIME() as DT;
```

Output:-

[image]

Second part of the solution:-

If your datetime (data) are in UTC then you can change your data (datetime to PST) through following SQL:-

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATETIME(), DATETIME_SUB( CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 8 hour);
```

Else if your data (datetime) are in PST then try to insert data without substracting 8 hours from your data. If your column data type is 'Datetime', then you will not have same problem.

Comment: But the problem is I couldn't determine how to store value in datetime column from Spark Java.

 df = df.withColumn("createdDate", from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp(), "PST"));

I get below error when storing this df.

BigQuery error was Provided Schema does not match Table. Field createdDate has changed type from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP